# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) witth Laravel and Vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have in backend this link `backend.com` and for frontend `frontend.com`

I want to lock my API backend for everyone except my frontend!

my `cors.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The headers are quite self-explainatory

Comment: @JosefKorbel I put my domain in `allowed_origins` but does not work and show me the error cors in console!

Comment: And is the backend server  responding with correct cors headers?

Comment: @JosefKorbel Yeah! that is why I asked!

Comment: @JosefKorbel I put it like this   'allowed_methods' => ['frontend.com'],

Comment: frontend.com is an origin so it should go in `allowed_origins`

Comment: @apokryfos with or without `https://` ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the protocol (and port if not using the default) are part of the origin

Comment: @apokryfos I have a question pls! what if I have the same API for mobile applications too! what should  I do to make my API just for API and mobile app!

Comment: Ok just to clarify what CORS does. If you're a user navigating to site A and site A tries to send a request on your behalf to site B (say your backend.com) then the browser will check the CORS headers to see  if site B allows this to happen. This only affects browsers so any mobile app (generally any HTTP client other than a browser) can access your backend without caring about CORS. If you want true security then use OAuth2 via e.g. laravel passport

Comment: Did you run php artisan config:clear after performing changes in cors.php file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in default global config, global main js file or where you use axios call:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'frontend.com';
```